# How do I get the current directory of a konsole kpart

Tags: c++, api, qt, kde-plasma, kparts

Exactly what it says on the tin.
Also is there any way to tell what is running inside the shell?*

I suppose I could do this by looking up finding process with matching parent pids* but is that portable to windows? And how would you look up current directory of a process given pid*.

*(most to least preferable) qt or kde api/other crossplatform api/*nix and windows api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TerminalInterfaceV2 might be exactly what I need, any extra info about it would be appreciated.